# Fields in register page is pre-filled out with name and email

Tags: user-registration

When I sign out from the [forum](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mingle-forum/) I'm using and click 'register', it takes me to the register page but some of the fields are already filled out. The name is in the 'email' field and the email address is in the 'password' field. How can I make it so that none of the fields get pre-filled out?

Below is a screenshot to give you a better idea of what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrjjI.png (I can't post images yet)

Comment: Why the negative vote? Just curious for future reference.

Comment: I down-voted your question because it is not useful and not related to WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is auto-filling the form in. Setting the `autocomplete` attribute on your form fields should disable this but your users may not appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not make it clear whether you want prevent this on your site or on other site. The high chance is that, the auto complete is done by your browser, not by the site itself.

If it is your site and you want to disable auto completing the fields, you can `autocomplete="off"` for the fields that you want autocomplete to be disabled. it will work in some browsers.

However, if the auto completion done by your browsers, you can clear saved form data. as you have not mentioned your browser name, i can't give browser specific help!

Comment: Thank you. However, I don't understand how I can add `autocomplete="off"` to the register page as, from my understanding, it is part of the core files which I'd need to alter. Is there a way to add the code to the fields without changing the core files?